# How can I use an UUID as an @Id for my @Entity properly?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I want to store a User entity from Spring Boot into a MySQL database and I want to use an `UUID` as an `Id`. But when I follow the online solutions I only get `The userId doesn't have a default value`. And I just can't figure out whats wrong. Here is the code:

**User entity:**

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Data
public class User {

    @JsonProperty("userId")
    @Column(name = "userId", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Id
    private UUID userId;
    
    @JsonProperty("email")
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;
    
    @JsonProperty("name")
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("surname")
    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    String surname;

    @JsonProperty("password")
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
}
```

**MySQL table:**

```sql
create table if not exists user (
   userId binary(16) not null primary key,
   name varchar(80) not null,
   surname varchar(80) not null,
   email varchar(120) not null,
   password varchar(120) not null
);
```

**The error message:**

```
SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000

2020-07-23 15:31:29.234 ERROR 16336 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'userId' doesn't have a default value
2020-07-23 15:31:29.251 ERROR 16336 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement] with root cause
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I have to [notice](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-simple) that:

> According to JPA only the following types should be used as identifier attribute types:
>
> - any Java primitive type
> - any primitive wrapper type
> - java.lang.String
> - java.util.Date (TemporalType#DATE)
> - java.sql.Date
> - java.math.BigDecimal
> - java.math.BigInteger
>
> *Any types used for identifier attributes beyond this list will not be portable*.

But, Hibernate [supports](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-uuid) `UUID` identifier value generation. This is supported through its `org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator` id generator.

You can use the default strategy, that is a version 4 (random) strategy according to IETF RFC 4122.

```java
@Id
@Column(name = "userId", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
@GeneratedValue
private UUID userId;
```

Or an alternative strategy which is a RFC 4122 version 1 (time-based) strategy (using IP address rather than mac address).

```java
@Id
@Column(name = "userId", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "custom-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "custom-uuid",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(
            name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class",
            value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy"
        )
    }
)
private UUID userId;
```